# while saving datas to db on springboot, program stopped it self without error

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, jsoup

i'm trying to build up my portfolio by springboot+jsoup+hadoop+R.
i successed to scrape datas(title,content,ip,writer etc..) from website by jsoup.
i add repo.save() method on it to save datas to mysql.
when i  performed it, it suddenly stop itself without error..;;
each page have about 40 post, if i scrap 1~30pages then it suppose to be about 1200raws had to be saved into db.

but it stops about 400raws and also sometimes it stops about 120raws.

i would like to know that how to fix this.

i attach codes for this. 
thank you for your reading my post! :)

```
[==== console log ====
    4.writer :dwk(175.223.*.*) 2018-03-19 02:10:40
    Hibernate: 
        insert 
        into
            dc_invest
            (content, ip_address, regdate, title, tno, updatedate, upload_date, writer) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    1.tno : 3113177
    2018-03-19 02:51:48.889  INFO 24571 --- \[       Thread-3\] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@1033576a: startup date \[Mon Mar 19 02:43:42 KST 2018\]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-03-19 02:51:48.904  INFO 24571 --- \[       Thread-3\] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2018-03-19 02:51:48.907  INFO 24571 --- \[       Thread-3\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2018-03-19 02:51:48.918  INFO 24571 --- \[       Thread-3\] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
============================================
 @Test
    public void InsertToDB2() throws IOException {

        // page Checker
        tunner:while (true) {
            int page = 1;
            System.out.println("======= " + page + "start ======");
            // target url.
            String url = "http://gall.dcinside.com/board/lists/?id=stock_new2&page=" + page;
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements title_no = doc.select("td.t_notice");

            // filtering
            int cnt = 0;
            while (cnt < 4) {
                title_no.remove(0);
                cnt++;
            }
            // 1.Getting tno.
            for (Element no : title_no) {
                System.out.println("1.tno : " + no.text());
                String no_ = no.text();
                WebDc dc = new WebDc();
                dc.setTno(Long.parseLong(no_));
                // 2.Getting title.
                Document tno_doc = Jsoup
                        .connect("http://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=stock_new2&no=" + no_ + "&page=" + page)
                        .get();
                Elements titles = tno_doc.select("dl.wt_subject dd");
                for (Element title : titles) {
                    System.out.println("2.Title : " + title.text());
                    dc.setTitle(title.text());
                    Document title_content = Jsoup
                            .connect("http://gall.dcinside.com/board/view/?id=stock_new2&no=" + no_ + "&page=" + page)
                            .get();
                    // 3. Getting contents
                    Element content = title_content.select("div.s_write").first();
                        // contents checker
                        if (content.hasText()) {
                            System.out.println(content.text());
                            dc.setContent(content.text());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("there is no letters");

                        }
                        // 4. Getting writer&ip&date.
                        Element writer = title_content.select("span.user_nick_nm").first();
                        Element ip = title_content.select("li.li_ip").first();
                        Element date = title_content.select("div.w_top_right b").first();
                        System.out.println("4.writer :" + writer.text() + "(" + ip.text() + ")" + " " + date.text());
                        dc.setWriter(writer.text());
                        dc.setIpAddress(ip.text());
                        dc.setUploadDate(date.text());
                        repo.save(dc);
                    }
                }

            // page limiter & checker
            System.out.println("==== Done Of " + page + " ====");
            if(page < 30){
                page++;
            } else{
                break tunner;
            }
            }
        } // while
============= domain =========
package com.example.domain;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
import org.jboss.logging.FormatWith;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "dc_invest")
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "db_no")
@ToString
public class WebDc {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Long db_no;
    private Long tno;
    // for making LONGTEXT
    @Column(length=1000000000)
    private String title;
    private String writer;
    @Column(length=1000000000)
    private String content;
    private String ipAddress;


    private String uploadDate;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp regdate;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp updatedate;

}][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm starting in Hibernate but I've had such a problem before. It always happened with the same request. Then I saw that I was opening as many connections as my look allowed. I had to find a way to not open so many connections. From what I understand, you're heading for it. Hope this helps.

Comment: only mysql connected to eclipse :(
(there is only one connection)